# Differentiating two dictionaries key sets to generate result dictionary

Tags: python

I have,

```
dict1={a:1, b:2, c:3}
dict2={a:3, c:7}
```

I want to find out what keys I have in dict1 that I don't have in dict2.  So I do

```
diff_as_set = set(dict1.keys()) - set (dict2.keys())
```

This gives me: `b`

However, I want a dictionary which contains all the key value mappings from dict1 for all keys that are not in dict 2 so I then do:

```
diff_as_dict = {k:v for k,v in dict1 if k in diff_as_set}
```

I get:

```
diff_as_dict = {k:v for k, v in dict1 if k in diff_as_set}
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't tested it (yet) but here's a recipe for a "setdict" which gives you set operations on a dict: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577471-setdict/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of going through the entire dict to pick out the ones that match your set, just iterate the set.

```
diff_as_dict = {k:dict1[k] for k in diff_as_set}
```

Example:

```
>>> dict1={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> dict2={'a':3, 'c':7}
>>> diff_as_set = set(dict1.keys()) - set (dict2.keys())
>>> diff_as_set
set(['b'])
>>> diff_as_dict = {k:dict1[k] for k in diff_as_set}
>>> diff_as_dict
{'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looping over a dict only provides keys, you need to use:

```
diff_as_dict = {k:v for k, v in dict1.iteritems() if k in diff_as_set}
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or use `.items()` for Python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `.iteritems()` part:

```
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
dict2 = {'a':3, 'c':7}
newdict = {k : v for k,v in dict1.iteritems() if not(k in dict2)}
```

After this, `newdict` is equal to `{'b': 2}`. This does everything in one go.